# Download files with python in a specifid path?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Hello i want do download a file with python, it works great but how can i save the file in a specifid path?
MY CODE:

```
url144 = "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/815696193354203157/817144742693437490/msgbox.vbs"
r = requests.get(url144, allow_redirects=True)
open("msgbox.vbs", "wb").write(r.content)
```

Comment: simple, instead of `"msgbox.vbs"` you put in your open `"/path/where/you/want/your/file/msgbox.vbs"`, like for example `open("C:/users/temal/documents/msgbox.vbs", "wb")`

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it exactly right, there is nothing to be improved in your code ! To change the path its saved to, just put it in the first argument to the `opne` call !

Answer (score 0):

like [Copperfield](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5644961/copperfield) said

your codes must be like this:

```
url144 = "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/815696193354203157/817144742693437490/msgbox.vbs"
r = requests.get(url144, allow_redirects=True)

open("/path/where/you/want/your/file/msgbox.vbs", "wb").write(r.content)
```

Answer (score -1):

You just need to do it using "with" which will close file once operation is completed

```
with open("msgbox.vbs", "wb") as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

Comment: and where is the path?